# Playwright lighthouse integration - Error: Cannot find module 'lighthouse/report/generator/report-generator'

Tags: javascript, playwright, lighthouse, playwright-test, playwright-lighthouse

I'm trying to implement Playwright tests with lighthouse to get performance metrics. using library and using the sample code - https://github.com/abhinaba-ghosh/playwright-lighthouse. but I'm getting error, please refer attached image.

[image]

Comment: do you have the sample repository where the issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

`const ReportGenerator = require('Lighthouse/report/generator/report-generator')`

to

`const ReportGenerator = require('Lighthouse/report/generator/report-generator').default`

and see if it's work